# Convert different shades of a color in an image to one color

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, rgb

How can I convert the light gray background color (with variation in its shades) to a single color, say light gray? I want the dark gray color embedded on top of the background color to be one single color as well. Until now, what I have done is to assign these two regions with two closest color names ('lightgray' and 'dimgray') and minimize the sum of squared differences for each pixel's r,g,b and get the closest color from webcolors module.

```
rd = (r_c - requested_color[0]) ** 2
gd = (g_c - requested_color[1]) ** 2
bd = (b_c - requested_color[2]) ** 2
```

**Original image:**

[image]

**Image produced from my python code:**

[image]

You can see that that along the boundaries I am not able to get the light gray color as you could see in the original image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called thresholding.

A general introduction of how to do this with OpenCV and Python can be found here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#gsc.tab=0

I have adapted some parameters of the code there:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,7)
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,160,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,31,5)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,31,5)
titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)',
'Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']
images = [img, th1, th2, th3]
for i in xrange(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the resulting image, the problem with your image is the strong variation in background intensity. Without knowing the origin of your images, I'd start with one of the following two options before trying to solve this by software:

1.) Get a more uniform illumination

2.) If not possible, and if illumination is the same for all images, make an empty image of background only and subtract it from your other images, in order to get more uniform illumination.

It is important to understand that this is not a software issue: In the border areas, the background is really darker than the structure in positions near the middle of the image. You can check this by checking gray values of single pixels. Only your eye is very good in compensating for this. The adaptive thresholding techniques listed below try to find an appropriate local threshold, but there is a limit to this. You may be able to find more adequate parameters, though, but first thing I'd recommend is working on uniformity of illumination.

[image]

[EDIT]

I have added an additional bit of code below for playing around with the images which allows you to

- Adapt the threshold with a slider
- Use the right mouse botton to see the original image again, inspect
  gray values at different mouse positions, and by clicking the right
  mouse button again, change back to threshold view and use gray value
  of last mouse position as new threshold value.

.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

mode = ""
Schwelle =0

def nothing(x):
    pass

def read_pixel(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global mode, Schwelle
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if mode == "Analyse":
            ix,iy = x,y
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            img2=img.copy()
            cv2.putText(img2,str(ix)+" "+str(iy)+": "+str(img[y,x]),(50,50), font, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)      
            cv2.imshow('image',img2)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        if mode == "Analyse":
            mode=""
            Schwelle=img[y,x]
            cv2.createTrackbar('Schwelle','image',Schwelle,255,nothing)            
        else:
            mode = "Analyse"
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        Schwelle= img[y,x] 

img =cv2.imread('image.png',0)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',read_pixel)
cv2.createTrackbar('Schwelle','image',128,255,nothing)

while(1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

    if mode != "Analyse":
        Schwelle = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Schwelle','image')
        ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,Schwelle,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imshow('image',thresh1)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution...it's helpful. However, I have one question on details of the threholding images: Even though thresholding is making the image better around the boundaries, it is making the internal region lighter (the region with dark gray color). Is it possible to obtain an image that has the internal region from image #2 and the boundary region from image # 3 (or #4)?

Comment: I need to better understand some of your constraints and intentions first: 1.) Do you have more similar images to inspect? If yes, can you provide some of them? (covering the variation aspect) 2.) What is your final goal in terms of accuracy, do you want to vizualize, do you want to measure area, do you want to find the centroid ...

Comment: Hi...in reference to your comment: 1) I added two pictures to the update section in the question. 2) My goal is to calculate the number of pixels (fraction of total figure area) occupied by the dark gray color.

Comment: I have one question about changing the array size of the image: currently, the output array for the image after thresholding is of size `(160, 1043)`...is there a way to provide a custom size for the output array obtained after thresholding? The documentation on the functions used by `cv2` is scarce and lacks explanation on the variables used.

Comment: The output is the same size as the input. You can change image size by using the resize function cv2.resize() which is part of the tutorial quoted above.

Comment: Thanks for the resize function...but, the thresholding is not working as desired with that edit. I have attached an updated image in the question to show that the middle region is not capturing the grey region as close to the original image...and as such, that is the important region that I want to capture in addition to the boundaries which have been captured well in that image.

Comment: I think I have the answer to the issue I described above. Taking a more coarser mesh size helps in capturing more of the gray region. Thanks